# Especificar elemento para não receber propriedades dos outros elementos principais

Tags: html, css

Tenho um menu e eu queria apenas especificar um elemento para ele não receber as mesmas propriedades aplicadas nos demais, no caso o elemento seria #lk "PRODUTOS" ele está recebendo todos os atributos que foram aplicados em outros elementos, mas eu pretendo não aplicar nenhum tipo de atributo nele, como eu faço para ignorar os atributos inseridos nele??

```css
body{background-color:#6C9;}
*{ padding:0px; margin:;}
input{ display:none;
}
.menu{ width:100%; 
height:52px; 
background-color: #333; 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.menu ul{ list-style:none; 
position:relative; 
top:2px; 
}
.menu ul li{ width:150px; 
float:left;
}
.menu label, .menu a{ padding:15px; 
display:block; 
text-decoration:none; 
text-align:center; 
background-color:#FFF; 
color: #06F; 
user-select:none; 
transition:all 0.3s linear;
}
.menu ul ul{ position:absolute; 
top:50px; 
visibility:;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul{ visibility:visible;
}
.menu label:hover, .menu a:hover{ background-color:#CCC;
}
.menu ul ul li{ float:none;
}
.menu ul ul li label, .menu ul ul li a{ border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
background-color: #F93; 
}
hr#hr1{ position:absolute; 
left:149px; 
top:-3px; 
height:35px;
}

/*sub*/
.sub{ position:fixed; 
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
left:0px; 
right:0px; 
background-color:#3CF; 
display:;
}
#ln1:hover .sub{ display:block;}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
<input type="checkbox" class="rd" id="t1"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="rd" id="t2"/>
<ul>
  <li id="ln"><label for="t1">News<hr id="hr1"></label></li>
  <li id="ln1"><label for="t1">Serviços</label>
   
   <ul>
     <div class="sub">
      <li><a href="#" id="lk">PRODUTOS-01</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="lk">PRODUTOS-02</a></li>
     </div>
   </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li id="ln"><label for="t2">Informações</label>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Links</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro nunca use IDs com o mesmo nome. Cada ID é único e só pode ser aplicada a UM elemento.

Mas caso vc quera apenas fazer uma variação no nome do ID vc pode fazer a seleção do atributo usando um <kbd>^</kbd> para selecionar apenas o atributo que começa com o mesmo nome tipo: `[id^="lk"]` isso significa qualquer ID que começa com **lk** por exemplo `id="lk1"` e `id="lk2"`. Então vc conseguem com o attr pegar os dois IDs de uma vez.

Repare que com esse css eu limpei todos os estilos que são aplicado nos IDs dentro do `.menu` para baixo

```
.menu [id^="lk"] {
    all: unset !important;
}
```

Veja o exemplo aplicado no seu código

```css
body{background-color:#6C9;}
*{ padding:0px; margin:;}
input{ display:none;
}
.menu{ width:100%; 
height:52px; 
background-color: #333; 
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.menu ul{ list-style:none; 
position:relative; 
top:2px; 
}
.menu ul li{ width:150px; 
float:left;
}
.menu label, .menu a{ padding:15px; 
display:block; 
text-decoration:none; 
text-align:center; 
background-color:#FFF; 
color: #06F; 
user-select:none; 
transition:all 0.3s linear;
}
.menu ul ul{ position:absolute; 
top:50px; 
visibility:;
}
.menu ul li:hover ul{ visibility:visible;
}
.menu label:hover, .menu a:hover{ background-color:#CCC;
}
.menu ul ul li{ float:none;
}
.menu ul ul li label, .menu ul ul li a{ border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
background-color: #F93; 
}


.menu [id^="lk"] {
all: unset;
}

hr#hr1{ position:absolute; 
left:149px; 
top:-3px; 
height:35px;
}

/*sub*/
.sub{ position:fixed; 
width:100%; 
height:100%; 
left:0px; 
right:0px; 
background-color:#3CF; 
display:;
}
#ln1:hover .sub{ display:block;}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <input type="checkbox" class="rd" id="t1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="rd" id="t2"/>
    <ul>
        <li id="ln"><label for="t1">News<hr id="hr1"></label></li>
        <li id="ln1"><label for="t1">Serviços</label>
        
        <ul>
            <div class="sub">
            <li><a href="#" id="lk1">PRODUTOS-01</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" id="lk2">PRODUTOS-02</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
        </li>
        
        <li id="ln"><label for="t2">Informações</label>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Links</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
</nav>
```

Comment: Hugo! eu não consegui limpar o efeito hover da linha: .menu label:hover, .menu a:hover{ background-color:#CCC;} eu fiz assim, .menu a:hover [id^="lk"] { all:unset; }

Comment: @ElienayJunior isso é por causa da hierarquia de prioridade de classes, editei a resposta e coloquei um important, dessa forma `all: unset !important;` e agora limpou 100%. O restante do estilo que vc quiser colocar tem que vir apos o unset ok, tipo `all: unset !important; color black;` por exemplo

Comment: Eu acabei de descobri outro jeito!  .menu #lk1, .menu #lk2 { all:unset; }

Comment: @ElienayJunior sim assim tb acredito que funcione, porém usando o [id^="lk"] vc não precisa ficar repetindo linhas de css. De qq forma a mágica mesmo fica por conta do `all:unset`

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas maneiras:

1) usar o seletor `:not` para aplicar a tudo que o seletor pegar, menos algo.
Por exemplo, no elemento que você não quer coloque um `ID` diferente, `lkProdutos` por exemplo, então nos seletores que afetam esse link, use o `not`, assim:

```
.menu ul ul li a:not(#lkProdutos){  .... }
```

2) usar um *CSS Reset* no elemento, ou seja, "limpar" os estilos, trazendo o elemento para o seu estilo original. Tem um texto interessante sobre isso aqui: http://blog.thiagobelem.net/css-reset-o-que-e-e-como-usar

Basicamente, fazer um seletor para o elemento e remover os estilos indesejados:

```
#lkProdutos {
  /* reset dos estilos */
}
```